# Live Edit fails with "CLOUD_CONTROLLER_URL is not set in the env"

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, devops, liveedit

When activating "Live Edit", the node instance fails to start.
I have no command in my `manifest.yml` file, but a script starts in my package.json. 
See the log below.

I'm running node 4.3.2 with IBM SDK for Node.js with Buildpack v3.2-20160315-1257.

```
2016-04-21T16:14:41.715+0200[API/6]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"0a14007e-b149-43e3-9632-f7a760309ebe", "instance"=>"16a7377582474236b301bd45d924e239", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248081}
2016-04-21T16:14:41.711+0200[API/2]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"0a14007e-b149-43e3-9632-f7a760309ebe", "instance"=>"16a7377582474236b301bd45d924e239", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248081}
2016-04-21T16:14:41.694+0200[DEA/153]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-04-21T16:15:35.594+0200[DEA/168]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:15:40.371+0200[API/5]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"0a14007e-b149-43e3-9632-f7a760309ebe", "instance"=>"ba2af471fdf7449c8168c086566e8c07", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248140}
2016-04-21T16:15:52.584+0200[API/2]OUTUpdated app with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 ({"name"=>"EmentoApi", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>512, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
2016-04-21T16:15:57.086+0200[API/4]OUTUpdated app with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 ({"route"=>"615b7bb1-34d3-436e-b52d-eef9e86118ba"})
2016-04-21T16:16:05.702+0200[API/1]OUTUpdated app with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 ({"console"=>true, "state"=>"STOPPED"})
2016-04-21T16:16:07.969+0200[DEA/70]OUTGot staging request for app with id 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:16:10.424+0200[API/4]OUTUpdated app with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 ({"console"=>true, "state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-04-21T16:16:10.578+0200[STG/70]OUT-----> Downloaded app package (44K)
2016-04-21T16:16:10.992+0200[STG/70]OUT-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (2.5M)
2016-04-21T16:16:12.343+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.2-20160315-1257
2016-04-21T16:16:12.343+0200[STG/0]OUT
2016-04-21T16:16:12.348+0200[STG/0]OUT Based on Cloud Foundry Node.js Buildpack v1.5.4
2016-04-21T16:16:12.355+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Creating runtime environment
2016-04-21T16:16:12.368+0200[STG/0]OUT NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
2016-04-21T16:16:12.369+0200[STG/0]OUT NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
2016-04-21T16:16:12.373+0200[STG/0]OUT NODE_ENV=development
2016-04-21T16:16:12.373+0200[STG/0]OUT NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
2016-04-21T16:16:12.378+0200[STG/0]OUT npm scripts will see NODE_ENV=production (not 'development')
2016-04-21T16:16:12.379+0200[STG/0]OUT https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production
2016-04-21T16:16:12.380+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Installing binaries
2016-04-21T16:16:12.402+0200[STG/0]OUT engines.node (package.json): 4.x
2016-04-21T16:16:12.403+0200[STG/0]OUT engines.npm (package.json): unspecified (use default)
2016-04-21T16:16:12.406+0200[STG/0]OUT Resolving node version 4.x via 'node-version-resolver'
2016-04-21T16:16:12.627+0200[STG/0]OUT Installing IBM SDK for Node.js (4.3.2) from cache
2016-04-21T16:16:13.594+0200[STG/0]OUT Using default npm version: 2.14.12
2016-04-21T16:16:13.915+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Restoring cache
2016-04-21T16:16:14.214+0200[STG/0]OUT - node_modules
2016-04-21T16:16:14.214+0200[STG/0]OUT Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
2016-04-21T16:16:14.224+0200[STG/0]OUT - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
2016-04-21T16:16:14.225+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Checking and configuring service extensions before installing dependencies
2016-04-21T16:16:14.388+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Building dependencies
2016-04-21T16:16:14.390+0200[STG/0]OUT Pruning any extraneous modules
2016-04-21T16:16:15.605+0200[STG/0]OUT Installing node modules (package.json)
2016-04-21T16:16:16.984+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Checking and configuring service extensions after installing dependencies
2016-04-21T16:16:17.155+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Installing App Management
2016-04-21T16:16:23.979+0200[STG/0]OUT The following utilities are configured to be enabled and will be installed now: devconsole, shell, inspector
2016-04-21T16:16:23.995+0200[STG/0]OUT Installing utility: devconsole
2016-04-21T16:16:24.011+0200[STG/0]OUT Installing utility: inspector
2016-04-21T16:16:24.027+0200[STG/0]OUT Installing utility: shell
2016-04-21T16:16:25.811+0200[STG/0]OUT Installing common dependency: App Management Node runtime
2016-04-21T16:16:25.864+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Caching build
2016-04-21T16:16:25.882+0200[STG/0]OUT Clearing previous node cache
2016-04-21T16:16:25.888+0200[STG/0]OUT Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
2016-04-21T16:16:25.889+0200[STG/0]OUT - node_modules
2016-04-21T16:16:26.358+0200[STG/0]OUT - bower_components (nothing to cache)
2016-04-21T16:16:26.648+0200[STG/0]OUT-----> Build succeeded!
2016-04-21T16:16:27.279+0200[STG/0]OUT ├── cfenv@1.0.3
2016-04-21T16:16:27.280+0200[STG/0]OUT └── express@4.12.4
2016-04-21T16:16:27.279+0200[STG/0]OUT ├── body-parser@1.15.0
2016-04-21T16:16:27.280+0200[STG/0]OUT ├── cloudant@1.4.1
2016-04-21T16:16:27.293+0200[STG/0]ERR
2016-04-21T16:16:35.814+0200[STG/70]OUT-----> Uploading droplet (36M)
2016-04-21T16:16:40.368+0200[DEA/168]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-04-21T16:16:40.380+0200[API/5]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"0a14007e-b149-43e3-9632-f7a760309ebe", "instance"=>"ba2af471fdf7449c8168c086566e8c07", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248200}
2016-04-21T16:16:40.802+0200[DEA/70]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:16:45.769+0200[DEA/70]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-04-21T16:16:45.784+0200[API/4]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"248fd08a82e4479ea6e4d11270d12504", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248205}
2016-04-21T16:16:45.785+0200[API/1]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"248fd08a82e4479ea6e4d11270d12504", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248205}
2016-04-21T16:18:05.700+0200[DEA/121]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:18:11.791+0200[DEA/121]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-04-21T16:18:11.806+0200[API/0]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"aaad4256abfa47d0b1012954aa757b84", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248291}
2016-04-21T16:18:11.807+0200[API/0]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"aaad4256abfa47d0b1012954aa757b84", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248291}
2016-04-21T16:18:40.698+0200[DEA/25]OUTRemoving crash for app with id 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:18:40.699+0200[DEA/25]OUTStopped app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:18:40.698+0200[DEA/25]OUTStopping app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:18:50.461+0200[DEA/120]OUTRemoving crash for app with id 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:18:50.462+0200[DEA/120]OUTStopping app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:18:50.463+0200[DEA/120]OUTStopped app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:19:05.651+0200[DEA/43]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRruntime.panic(0x7429c0, 0xc208000920)
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]OUTActivating app management utilities: devconsole, shell, inspector
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 16 [running]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRmain.main()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/agent.go:47 +0xce
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRgithub.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote.NewProxy(0xc2080400c0, 0xc208023110, 0xc208023110)
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 20 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRruntime.goexit()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0xf5
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:2606
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRruntime.goexit()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgithub.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/registry.func·004()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 21 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRruntime.goexit()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRpanic: CLOUD_CONTROLLER_URL is not set in the env
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRcreated by os/signal.init·1
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 18 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/proxy.go:33 +0x10f
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRgithub.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote.NewProxyAgent(0xc2080400c0, 0xc2080008b0, 0x35)
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRcreated by gopkg.in/fsnotify%2ev1.NewWatcher
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1/inotify.go:126
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRcreated by github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/security.NewAuthenticator
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/remote/main/main.go:35 +0xef
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRruntime.MHeap_Scavenger()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRos/signal.loop()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 17 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERRmain.createAgent(0x7f3d803d4318)
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:1976
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1/inotify.go:47 +0x240
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/os/signal/signal_unix.go:27 +0x32
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRbgsweep()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 19 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgithub.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/security.cacheLoop(0xc208004420, 0xc208004480)
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 22 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/security/authenticator_prod.go:67 +0x10f
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgoroutine 23 [runnable]:
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/security/authenticator_prod.go:40
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
2016-04-21T16:19:10.801+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/remote/main/main.go:24 +0x4e
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRcreated by github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/registry.(*ProxyRegistry).watchConfig
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/registry/registry.go:189 +0x1b7
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRrunfinq()
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/runtime/mheap.c:507
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/gocmd/go/src/pkg/os/signal/signal_unix.go:19
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERR /home/jenkins/workspace/Shuttle_Proxy_Agent_Continous_Build/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.rtp.raleigh.ibm.com/oeruntime/shuttle.git/remote/registry/registry.go:172
2016-04-21T16:19:10.802+0200[App/0]ERRgopkg.in/fsnotify%2ev1.(*Watcher).readEvents(0xc208042140)
2016-04-21T16:19:10.898+0200[DEA/43]ERRInstance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-04-21T16:19:10.912+0200[API/9]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"f38a1dfa609f4770b67e190371c93b58", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248350}
2016-04-21T16:19:10.919+0200[API/8]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"f38a1dfa609f4770b67e190371c93b58", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248350}
2016-04-21T16:19:42.856+0200[DEA/153]OUTRemoving crash for app with id 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:19:42.857+0200[DEA/153]OUTStopping app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:19:42.859+0200[DEA/153]OUTStopped app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:20:05.808+0200[DEA/92]OUTStarting app instance (index 0) with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2
2016-04-21T16:20:12.034+0200[API/3]OUTApp instance exited with guid 93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"93b42478-469e-445e-9463-1c797dec97f2", "version"=>"f7c1e270-ac53-4fde-b807-a154c7cb006e", "instance"=>"c5497a6215ef4b8da94dc1794665b135", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>2, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1461248412}
```

Answer (score 0):

The LiveEdit utility requires an additional 256MB of memory which the buildpack will automatically try to allocate during app startup.  Try increasing the overall memory and restage your application.

See the note in the LiveEdit section of the doc below for more details:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/develop/bluemixlive.html

Comment: This appears to be a bug in that one of the env variables is not set. You'll need to raise a bluemix defect.

Comment: This issue was fixed by recreating the app and the launch configuration. Increasing the memory was not enough by it self.